# Compression of large figures in .fig format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

My MATLAB script generates a figure from a timeseries data that, when saved, is over 200 MB in size. Is there a way to compress the figure to a lesser size in '*.fig' format? The compression has to be lossless so that I can zoom in and view the details in the figure. The figure has to be saved in *.fig format so that the axis property relations between subplots are preserved and I can use the data cursor tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*.fig` format cannot be saved as is in compressed form. The format is just not capable of it. But in MATLAB you can use functions [`zip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zip.html)  to compress files created by [`savefig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html?searchHighlight=savefig), and [`unzip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unzip.html) with passing to [`openfig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html). This way you can create simple script to load and save zipped `fig`s. Of course you will need to use a temp file, which should be taken care of as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, just found out that there is an option called 'compact' in savefig.

Comment: Right. It was introduced in 2014b, I am using an older one :) Just curious, how good is the compression of this one?